# Setting DataGridRow RowDetails visibility after toggling between TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, tabcontrol, rowdetails

I have a `TabControl`, in each `TabItem` there is a `DataGrid`. Each `DataGridRow` has a button on the `DataGridRowHeader`, which expands and collapses the `RowDetails`.

As I use the row details expansion functionality, so have set the VirtualizingPanel ScrollUnit to Pixel, so scrolling is a bit more natural.

The program captures which rows have been expanded in an `ObservableCollection&lt;int>` which holds the row index to expand.

When I toggle to a new `TabItem` and back to the original `TabItem`, it loses which rows have been expanded.

Upon the `DataContext` being changed, I'd like to use the `ObservableCollection` to reset the expanded rows. I have tried this in the `DataGrid` `DataContextChanged` event.

```
public class DataGridBehaviors : Behavior<DataGrid>{
    protected override void OnAttached(){
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged += DataGrid_DataContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching(){
        this.AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged -= DataGrid_DataContextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void DataGrid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
        ModuleGeometry oldModuleGeometry = (ModuleGeometry)e.OldValue;
        ModuleGeometry newModuleGeometry = (ModuleGeometry)e.NewValue;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            PerformRowExpansions(newModuleGeometry);
        });

        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(this.AssociatedObject);
        if (scrollViewer != null){
            /*
             * do some stuff
             */
        }
    }

    private void PerformRowExpansions(ModuleGeometry newModuleGeometry){
        ObservableCollection<int> tempExpandedIndexes = new ObservableCollection<int>(newModuleGeometry.ExpandedIndexes);
        newModuleGeometry.ExpandedIndexes = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()){
            foreach (int index in tempExpandedIndexes)
            {
                DataGridRow row = this.AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
                row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        else{
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>{
                foreach (int index in tempExpandedIndexes){
                    DataGridRow row = this.AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual{
        T child = default(T);

        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++){
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            if (child != null)
                break;
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't like doing this on rows that are not currently in the `VirtualizingPanel`.

How can I accomplish this? 
Should I just do the expand the currently virtualized rows? 
Should the `DataGrid` `ScrollViewer` be manipulated programmatically as well? How can I account for the rows not visible in the `ScrollViewer`?
Is there another object, other the `DataGridRow` that I should be setting the `RowDetails` `Visibility` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `DataGridRow` containers for the rows that are not currently in the `VirtualizingPanel`. That's how the virtualization works.

If you want to persist some information between tab switches, you should store the data to be persisted in your view models. You could for example bind the `Button` in the `DataGridRowHeader` to some command that adds and removes indexes from a collection in the underlying data class, i.e. the `DataContext` of the parent `DataGridRow`, `TabItem` or `TabControl`.

Trying to iterate through the visual `DataGridRow` containers won't work unless you disable the UI virtualization. And this may of course lead to performance issues.

Comment: Have put most of what you talked about in, though I'm just using code-behind. My issue now is restoring that stored data.

Comment: One more question: So if a bunch of RowDetails are set to visible and then the user scrolls them off the VirtualizingPanel, which causes the rows to be destroyed. Where does the DataGrid keep this information, because they're still expanded when you scroll them back into view?

Comment: The elements are re-created or re-used from a previous container and the details are still visible because of some property being set to true or Visible. But this won't help you.